# set opacity value to multiple modal in css

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have two modals which opens on different clicks. I want to set background opacity of inner modal as 0.9 and outer modal as 0.3.
How do I add css for the same?

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ZcLSE/2462/)

I am using bootstrap to display the modal.

Html

```
    <!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque vel vehicula erat. Phasellus vestibulum leo eu mi tempor blandit. Suspendisse eget iaculis lectus. Donec vitae tempus enim, quis tristique magna. Donec lobortis, sem ac pretium viverra, leo nisl consequat arcu, sit amet ullamcorper nunc turpis ac erat. In rutrum auctor ligula, quis mattis enim lacinia eu. Aliquam at magna a erat laoreet iaculis quis a justo. Donec porttitor vulputate massa, nec suscipit nisi mollis sed. In rutrum auctor ligula, quis mattis enim lacinia eu. Aliquam at magna a erat laoreet iaculis quis a justo. Donec porttitor vulputate massa, nec suscipit nisi mollis sed</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
               <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
               <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal2">Open Small Modal</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-dialog -->

     <!-- Modal 2 -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal2" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header2</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>This is a small moda2l.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal2">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- /.modal -->
```

css

```
.modal-body {
  max-height: calc(150vh - 300px);
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.modal-backdrop {
  opacity: 0.9;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

How about applying this CSS?

```
.modal-backdrop.in {
  opacity: 0.9;
}

.modal-backdrop.in + .modal-backdrop.in {
  opacity: 0.3;
}
```

Comment: I deleted my answer in favor of this one, because this is the right answer to do what you want.

Comment: Thank you @TahaPaksu you could keep your ones as JS based solution.

Comment: it doesnt work,.modal-backdrop.in + .modal-backdrop.in applies only to inner modal

Comment: Yes it should do so. `.modal-backdrop.in` is the outer modal, `.modal-backdrop.in + .modal-backdrop.in` is the inner modal.

Comment: You can use `0.3` for the outer and `0.6` for outer modals, then you'll have `0.9` for the whole darkness.

Comment: @TahaPaksu is it not possible to just apply opacity to a modal not whole background

Comment: You want backdrops to be opaque or modal windows?

Comment: The opacity of Modal? are you sure?

Answer (score 1):

You can set the background opacity using an `RGBa` (red, green, blue, alpha) value for `background-color` in CSS:

The `alpha` value sets the opacity of the color as a percentage (0.3 = 30%, 0.9 = 90%).

```
#myModal {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}     

#myModal2 {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

set the child modal window css property `background: rgba(0,0,0,.3)`

```
.modal .modal {
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.3);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ZcLSE/2483/